# Lenovo Wifi doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04/16.04. Please help

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, network-manager, lenovo

Ubuntu can't find my wlan devices. iwconfig doen't list any wireless lan.
rfkill lisst all output is empty.

Please see my wireless info

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 07 Jul 2019 01:33 IST +0530

Booted last: 07 Jul 2019 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-154-generic #181-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 25 05:29:03 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo AR8162 Fast Ethernet [17aa:3978]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0294 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### secure boot #######################

'mokutil' is not installed (package "mokutil").

##### lsmod #############################

iwlwifi               200704  0
wl                   6447104  0
cfg80211              565248  2 wl,iwlwifi
8192eu                929792  0
ideapad_laptop         28672  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    20480  1 ideapad_laptop
video                  40960  2 i915,ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether <MAC 'docker0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

169.254.0.0/16 dev docker0  scope link  metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf']
nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager
    Wicd

Running:

root     28909     1  2 01:33 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         docker0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBridge
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bridge
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'docker0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/2
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       docker0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    yes
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     docker0
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       3ba52cb1-449e-4ae3-be3d-729aaf345241
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               yes
BRIDGE.SLAVES:                          
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{10}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   3ba52cb1-449e-4ae3-be3d-729aaf345241 | docker0
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.17.0.1/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        AR8162 Fast Ethernet
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         alx
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq
[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/moto g4]] (600 root)
[connection] id=moto g4 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=moto g4 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SG]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SG | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=SG | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NetCubicles]] (600 root)
[connection] id=NetCubicles | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=NetCubicles | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Searching....................]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Searching.................... | type=wifi | permissions=user:kantajit:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Searching....................
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Searching.................... 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Searching.................... 1 | type=wifi | permissions=user:kantajit:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Searching....................
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NETGEAR]] (600 root)
[connection] id=NETGEAR | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=NETGEAR | bssid=<MAC address> | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Basanti kutto k samne mat nachna]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Basanti kutto k samne mat nachna | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Basanti kutto k samne mat nachna | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/moto g4 2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=moto g4 2 | type=wifi | permissions=user:kantajit:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=moto g4
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Basanti kutto k samne mat nachna 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Basanti kutto k samne mat nachna 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Basanti kutto k samne mat nachna
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/moto g4 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=moto g4 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=moto g4 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

docker0   no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

docker0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-154-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-13.ucode
srcversion:     CB5AC244E1344F14798FC7E
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-154-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-154-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     00D38A27B7E3C7B97C238FC
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-154-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-154-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     F19202ED8FEFA1B3A34B1F2
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-154-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[8192eu]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-154-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8192eu.ko
version:        v4.3.1.1_11320.20140505
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL
srcversion:     DC4944779709F5666CC49A7
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-154-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           rtw_ips_mode:The default IPS mode (int)
parm:           rtw_usb_rxagg_mode:int
parm:           rtw_qos_opt_enable:int
parm:           ifname:The default name to allocate for first interface (charp)
parm:           if2name:The default name to allocate for second interface (charp)
parm:           rtw_initmac:charp
parm:           rtw_channel_plan:int
parm:           rtw_chip_version:int
parm:           rtw_rfintfs:int
parm:           rtw_lbkmode:int
parm:           rtw_network_mode:int
parm:           rtw_channel:int
parm:           rtw_mp_mode:int
parm:           rtw_wmm_enable:int
parm:           rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense:int
parm:           rtw_vcs_type:int
parm:           rtw_busy_thresh:int
parm:           rtw_ht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_bw_mode:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_enable:int
parm:           rtw_rx_stbc:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_amsdu:int
parm:           rtw_lowrate_two_xmit:int
parm:           rtw_rf_config:int
parm:           rtw_power_mgnt:int
parm:           rtw_smart_ps:int
parm:           rtw_low_power:int
parm:           rtw_wifi_spec:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_cfg:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_type:int
parm:           rtw_enusbss:int
parm:           rtw_hwpdn_mode:int
parm:           rtw_hwpwrp_detect:int
parm:           rtw_hw_wps_pbc:int
parm:           rtw_max_roaming_times:The max roaming times to try (uint)
parm:           rtw_mc2u_disable:int
parm:           rtw_80211d:Enable 802.11d mechanism (int)
parm:           rtw_notch_filter:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2:Enable only for P2P (uint)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_lmt_enable:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_by_rate:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_phy_file_path:The path of phy parameter (charp)
parm:           rtw_load_phy_file:PHY File Bit Map (int)
parm:           rtw_decrypt_phy_file:Enable Decrypt PHY File (int)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

[8192eu]
if2name: wlan%d
ifname: wlan%d
rtw_80211d: 0
rtw_ampdu_amsdu: 0
rtw_ampdu_enable: 1
rtw_antdiv_cfg: 2
rtw_antdiv_type: 0
rtw_busy_thresh: 40
rtw_bw_mode: 33
rtw_channel: 1
rtw_channel_plan: 88
rtw_chip_version: 0
rtw_decrypt_phy_file: 0
rtw_enusbss: 0
rtw_ht_enable: 1
rtw_hwpdn_mode: 2
rtw_hwpwrp_detect: 0
rtw_hw_wps_pbc: 1
rtw_initmac: (null)
rtw_ips_mode: 1
rtw_lbkmode: 0
rtw_load_phy_file: 68
rtw_low_power: 0
rtw_lowrate_two_xmit: 1
rtw_max_roaming_times: 2
rtw_mc2u_disable: 0
rtw_mp_mode: 0
rtw_network_mode: 0
rtw_notch_filter: 0
rtw_power_mgnt: 1
rtw_qos_opt_enable: 0
rtw_rf_config: 5
rtw_rfintfs: 2
rtw_rx_stbc: 1
rtw_smart_ps: 2
rtw_tx_pwr_by_rate: 0
rtw_tx_pwr_lmt_enable: 0
rtw_usb_rxagg_mode: 2
rtw_vcs_type: 1
rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense: 2
rtw_wifi_spec: 0
rtw_wmm_enable: 1

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf]
blacklist ideapad_laptop

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x1969:0x1090 (alx)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8192eu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
# USB device 0x:0x (r8188eu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x4727 (brcmsmac)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan2"

##### dmesg #############################

[ 2525.269748] RTL871X: rtw_indicate_scan_done(wlan0)
[ 2526.213130] RTL871X: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlan0) Enter 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_IDLE
[ 2526.213146] RTL871X: rtl8192e_set_FwPwrMode_cmd: Mode=1 SmartPS=2 UAPSD=0
[ 2526.275358] RTL871X: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlan0) Leave 802.11 power save - WIFI-LPS_CTRL_LEAVE
[ 2526.275371] RTL871X: rtl8192e_set_FwPwrMode_cmd: Mode=0 SmartPS=2 UAPSD=0
[ 2530.222074] RTL871X: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlan0) Enter 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_IDLE
[ 2530.222092] RTL871X: rtl8192e_set_FwPwrMode_cmd: Mode=1 SmartPS=2 UAPSD=0
[ 2532.226547] RTL871X: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlan0) Leave 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_BUSY
[ 2532.226561] RTL871X: rtl8192e_set_FwPwrMode_cmd: Mode=0 SmartPS=2 UAPSD=0
[ 2544.730506] RTL871X: rtw_indicate_scan_done(wlan0)
[ 2548.262383] RTL871X: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlan0) Enter 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_IDLE
[ 2548.262396] RTL871X: rtl8192e_set_FwPwrMode_cmd: Mode=1 SmartPS=2 UAPSD=0
[ 2550.266933] RTL871X: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlan0) Leave 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_BUSY
[ 2550.266947] RTL871X: rtl8192e_set_FwPwrMode_cmd: Mode=0 SmartPS=2 UAPSD=0
[ 2554.275858] RTL871X: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlan0) Enter 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_IDLE
[ 2554.275873] RTL871X: rtl8192e_set_FwPwrMode_cmd: Mode=1 SmartPS=2 UAPSD=0
[ 2560.289221] RTL871X: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlan0) Leave 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_BUSY
[ 2560.289228] RTL871X: rtl8192e_set_FwPwrMode_cmd: Mode=0 SmartPS=2 UAPSD=0
[ 2570.311735] RTL871X: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlan0) Enter 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_IDLE
[ 2570.311748] RTL871X: rtl8192e_set_FwPwrMode_cmd: Mode=1 SmartPS=2 UAPSD=0
[ 2574.415803] RTL871X: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlan0) Leave 802.11 power save - WIFI-LPS_CTRL_LEAVE
[ 2574.415817] RTL871X: rtl8192e_set_FwPwrMode_cmd: Mode=0 SmartPS=2 UAPSD=0
[ 2582.338748] RTL871X: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlan0) Enter 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_IDLE
[ 2582.338761] RTL871X: rtl8192e_set_FwPwrMode_cmd: Mode=1 SmartPS=2 UAPSD=0
[ 2586.347534] RTL871X: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlan0) Leave 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_BUSY
[ 2586.347542] RTL871X: rtl8192e_set_FwPwrMode_cmd: Mode=0 SmartPS=2 UAPSD=0
[ 2588.352095] RTL871X: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlan0) Enter 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_IDLE
[ 2588.352110] RTL871X: rtl8192e_set_FwPwrMode_cmd: Mode=1 SmartPS=2 UAPSD=0
[ 2590.356649] RTL871X: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlan0) Leave 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_BUSY
[ 2590.356664] RTL871X: rtl8192e_set_FwPwrMode_cmd: Mode=0 SmartPS=2 UAPSD=0
[ 2593.702123] RTL871X: LeaveAllPowerSaveMode(wlan0): bSurpriseRemoved=1 Skip! (repeated 2 times)
[ 2593.702218] RTL871X: SetHwReg8192E(wlan0) HW_VAR_BASIC_RATE: BrateCfg(0x15d)
[ 2593.707561] RTL871X: rtw_ndev_uninit(wlan0)
[ 2593.745283] RTL871X: LeaveAllPowerSaveMode(wlan0): bSurpriseRemoved=1 Skip! (repeated 2 times)
[ 2593.745290] RTL871X: rtw_sta_flush(wlan0)
[ 2593.745340] RTL871X: +r871xu_dev_remove, hw_init_completed=1
[ 2593.745490] RTL871X: -r871xu_dev_remove, done
[ 2594.527486] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```